# In Swashbuckle how to I filter a model based on status code

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an api project where every method returns its response wrapped in an ApiResponse<> object.

The class looks like this

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<ResponseError> Errors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ResponseLinks Links { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ResponseMeta Meta { get; set; }
}
```

According to the Json Api spec http://jsonapi.org/ Data and Errors must never appear in the response together.

**1. How do I get the swagger document to only show Errors when the status code is not 200 and to exclude errors when it is 200?**  I could make 2 seperate objects, but I would really prefer to keep it as one class so the ApiResponse object can decide what is the correct way to construct itself.

**2. Also the swagger UI is listing all iterations of generics in the models** How do I clean it up so it only shows 1 ApiResponse model?

[Example of question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypzRX.png)